# How to fadein bootstrap modal on DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

When selected `DropDownList1`, the bootstrap modal gets fade out on `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="border: none">
                <div class="three-login">
                    <div class="three-login-head">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            ×</button>
                        <h4>
                            The Fastest Car Insurance Premium Calculator</h4>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: right">
            Car Brand
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 outer-addon1 left-addon">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #00aeff; border-color: #00aeff;">
                        <i class="fa fa-bitcoin" style="color: #fff"></i></span>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbrand" runat="server" class="showbtn" CssClass="form-control" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlbrand_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: right">
            Car Model
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 outer-addon1 left-addon">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #00aeff; border-color: #00aeff;">
                        <i class="fa fa-car" style="color: #fff"></i></span>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmodels" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlmodels_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-body -->
</div>
```

When I select 1st dropdownlist that is car brand the modal get fade out, in which case modal shouldn't fade

JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=ddlbrand.ClientID%>').select(function () {
            $('#myModal').addClass('in').removeClass('hide');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While writing question in SO, turn off capslock and turnoff `autopostback` to make JS execution work.

Comment: I want autopostback to be true, if js not working , then their is another way to do it ? @ArindamNayak

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, i think it would be helpful for others

This code is written in c# on ddlbrand_SelectedIndexChanged
 Code as follow

```
protected void ddlbrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlbrand.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowModal",  "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
    }
}
```